# How do you trigger a script after passing a sprit in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

In unity I want to trigger a camera follow script after the player passes a certain sprit in unity but I don't know if there is a component you could use on a sprit or something like that.

Comment: Is your game 2D? Or are you using a canvas that has an image component on it in world space?

Comment: yes the game is 2D

Comment: Just wanted to make sure. The provided answer should work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing you are referring to a sprite, if thats the case, just add a colider2D to the sprite and use onTriggerEnter2D() to check when the colider on your character touches the collider on your other object with something like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("I touched the sprite");
}
```

Comment: Do i check is trigger on the collider? Also how do I trigger a script in this script

Comment: inside the instance that has the collider you can perform the checks to see if its touching another collider and to trigger the script just replace "Debug.Log("I touched the sprite");" with your function and when the sprite touches the other collider your function will be called.